# Multi level dynamic flyout menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have the following structure for a flyout menu with pure CSS:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Base</a>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a>                
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employees</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a {text-decoration: none; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px}
ul{list-style: none; padding:0; margin:0}

.menu {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    width: 100%; height: auto; 
    background: #ccc;    
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0;   
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block
}
.menu li li {
    float:none;
}
.menu li a {
   padding: 0 5px;   
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background: #bbb
}
.menu li ul {
    padding:0; margin:0;
    background: #ddd;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;    
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;    
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    margin:0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    display:block
}
.menu li ul li {
    clear:both   
}
.menu li ul li a {   
    width: auto;
    display:block;
}
.menu li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;       
    top: 0; left: 72px;    
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0
}
.menu li ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0
}
.menu li ul li:hover ul li {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display:block    
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Wdr/)**

Everything is working fine for the first and second levels of the menu.
Second level (`.menu li ul`) is dynamic so if the length of an option has changed this should increase its width.

That's exactly where my question came from. I want that the third level always stays at the end of the second level, regardless the `width` of second level.

I'll try to make it more clear with the following images.

*This is what I have now:*

[image: What I have]

*Here is what happens when the lenght of an option is increased:*

[image: The problem]

*Following is how the menu should behave:*

[image: How I want it]

***Is that a way to do it with pure CSS?***

If not, what will be my best choice to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change `.menu li ul li ul {` to `position:relative` and `left: 100%` it will display next to the second level, but it creates a gap that I'm not sure how to get rid of.

Comment: Wow, just change position back to absolute, and left to 100% and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f66MM/
This seems to work. All I did was change `left:100%` in li ul li ul

```
a {text-decoration: none; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px}
ul{list-style: none; padding:0; margin:0}

.menu {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    width: 100%; height: auto; 
    background: #ccc;    
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0;   
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block
}

.menu li li {
    float:none;
}

.menu li a {
   padding: 0 5px;   
}

.menu li a:hover {
   background: #bbb
}

.menu li ul {
    padding:0; margin:0;
    background: #ddd;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;    
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;    
}

.menu li:hover ul {
    margin:0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    display:block
}

.menu li ul li {
    clear:both   
}

.menu li ul li a {   
    width: auto;
    display:block;
}

.menu li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;       
    top: 0; left: 100%;    
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0
}

.menu li ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0
}

.menu li ul li:hover ul li {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
}
```