# Dynamic fly out menus

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing a flyout menu bar similar to this one "[Multi level dynamic flyout menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672345/multi-level-dynamic-flyout-menu)" but with addition to the height of the sub menus that they have to be even/leveled. I mean if the bottoms of level 2 and the level 3 have to extend so the full fly out menu is a perfect rectangular.

For example, if the level 2 has 1 menu item and the level 3 has 5 items, then the level has to extend 4 more empty rows so its bottom levels with the bottom of level 3. See pictures [image][image]

I'm open to use jquery bootstrap if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried *anything* at all? If so, can you post that here? Otherwise, please read the [ask] page on how to formulate a great question...

Comment: Thanks guys. I will recompose my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In your current setup, you don't have any way to get an accurate height of the third-level menu, since it is hidden until hovered. However, you can get a pretty good estimate using `em` lengths. Then it is just a matter of setting a `height` on the appropriate elements.

Here's a jQuery function and example snippet that should do what you want.

```js
$(".menu > li > ul").each(function() {
  var me = $(this); //store a reference
  var children = $(me.find("li").toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("ul li") > $(b).find("ul li");
  })); //get children, sorted by number of third-level menu items
  var tallest = children.eq(0); //get tallest child
  var height = tallest.find("ul li").length; //get number of items
  children.find("ul").add(me).css("height", height + "em"); //set min-height
});
```

```css
a {text-decoration: none; font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px}
ul{list-style: none; padding:0; margin:0}

.menu {
  margin:0; padding:0;
  width: 100%; height: auto; 
  background: #ccc;    
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;   
}

.menu li {
  float:left;
  display:block
}

.menu li li {
  float:none;
}

.menu li a {
  padding: 0 5px;   
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #bbb
}

.menu li ul {
  padding:0; margin:0;
  background: #ddd;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;    
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;    
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  margin:0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display:block
}

.menu li ul li {
  clear:both   
}

.menu li ul li a {   
  width: auto;
  display:block;
}

.menu li ul li ul {
  position: absolute;       
  top: 0; left: 100%;    
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
}

.menu li ul li ul li {
  position: relative;
  display:none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
}

.menu li ul li:hover ul li {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Base</a>        
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Clientssssssssssssss</a>                
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Employees</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
</ul>
```